# How to get product Id from database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the product Id from the database by using the hidden input but am stuck; I'm getting the error `General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column 'product_id'`. How do I get the product Id from the database?

**Blade**

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
```

**Controller**

```php
Image::create(array_merge($formInput,
    [
        $id = $request->input('id'),
        $product_id = Product::find('id'),
        'product_id' => $product_id,

    ]));
```

**Updated**

This is my updated controller.

```
Image::create(array_merge($formInput,
[
    $id = $request->input('id'),
    $product = Product::get($id),
    'product_id' =>$product->id,

]));
```

Comment: `$product_id=Product::get('id'),` should be ` $product_id=Product::select('id')->get(),`

Comment: That also throws an error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.` @DhananjayKyada

Answer (score 0):

1. User `$id` instead of `'id'`
2. get `$product` object
3. Use the  `id` of the product
4. Use `::find(id)`

So in your code, change

```
  $id=$request->input('id'),
    $product_id=Product::get('id'),
    'product_id' =>$product_id,
```

to

```
  $id=$request->input('id'),
    $product=Product::find($id), /// I assume id is the PK
    'product_id' =>$product->id
```

Comment: That shows an error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server` @Danyal

Comment: Now I'm getting `Trying to get property of non-object` that error comes from this line `'product_id' =>$product->id,` @Danyal

Comment: you are missing this part `$product=Product::find($id), `

Comment: @user11710915 check the line properly, you have missed it out

Comment: what do you mean I'm missing this part? `$product=Product::find($id)` @Danyal

Comment: Please, check my updated controller in the question @Danyal

Comment: @user11710915 please change `$product=Product::get($id),
` to `$product=Product::find($id)`